# cannot add sms plugin to visual workflow

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows, sms

i am creating a flow in salesforce and following the instructions as given in the screen shot.

I am not being able to understand how to add the sms plugin in the flow (as per the instructions given below).

[image]

The link to the instructions i am following.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_3p_sms_2fa_login_flow.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Help Doc, have you performed step 7?

```
7. Create an Apex class.
```

Once you completed this step, after refresh your flow editor, you can see "SMSPlugin" will appear on the left-side Palette for choosing

**Note**: the sample code on the Help Doc is corrupted - it contains the line code - you need to remove them for each line

Comment: Yes. Thanks. That was all that I had to do. Refresh the editor. Thanks.